# NXOauth2Request IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

In my code I am calling code similar to the example code:

```
[NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                    onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://...your service URL..."]
                    usingParameters:nil withAccount:anAccount
                    sendProgressHandler:^(unsigned long long bytesSend, unsigned long long bytesTotal) {
                        // e.g., update a progress indicator
                    }
                    responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){
                        // Process the response
                    }]
```

The problem is that once the application has been inactive for a while and it tries to do this with old authentication data.

I receive the following error in the output window:

> oauthConnection Error: {"error":"invalid_grant"}

The bad thing is, that the response handler does not get called when this error occurs, so the application is in the dark about the state of the request. It would be OK, if we got at least an error back in the responseHandler.

Comment: So, do you have a programming question, or just a feature request for the author of `NXOAuth2Request`?

Comment: No Request Go right But after pressing accept button this error shows